# Why doesn't multilayered async functions catch error thrown at lowest level in node?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, mocha.js

I'm trying to test a failure mode of some mailing code which at the lowest level may throw an error.  All the layers between the test and the function which throws are all async and use await on the functions below them.  At the top level (also in an async function I have a try catch block.  However node is throwing an unhandled promise exception before the error propages to this level.

My test code looks like this

```
beforeEach(function() {
  //set default values - tests can change them
  this.reasons = '';
  this.reschedules = 0;
  this.params.cid = 35124;

  this.startTest = async () => {
    /*  this.confirmation is an async function under test, 
        this.mailer is a mock mailer with an async "send" method
        which will throw an error in the correct test */
    const doner = this.confirmation(this.mailer);  
    // ..other actions related to mocking database access made by confirmation
    await doner;
    return this.mailer.maildata; //provide info on parameters passed to this.mailer
  };
});
it('Failure to send is reported', async function() {
  this.mailer.sendResolve = false; //tell mock mailer to fail send request
  try {
    await this.startTest();
    expect(true).to.be.false;
  } catch(err) {
    expect(err).to.be.instanceOf(Error);
  }
});
```

the mock mailer is a bit like this

```
class Mailer {
    constructor(user,params){
...
    }
    ...
    async send(subject, to, cc, bcc) {
      this.maildata.subject = subject;
      if (to !== undefined) this.maildata.to = to;
      if (cc !== undefined) this.maildata.cc = cc;
      if (bcc !== undefined) this.maildata.bcc = bcc;
      if (!this.sendResolve) throw new Error('Test Error');
    }
    ...
 }
```

and a summary of the code under test

```
 module.exports = async function(mailer) {
    //get confirm data from database
    const cData = await confirm(mailer.params.cid, mailer.db);
    if (cData.count > 0) {
       // ... format the email message and build it into maildata
       await mailer.send(
        subject,
        emailAddress,
        null,
        process.env.PAS_MAIL_FROM,
        {
          pid:cData.pid,
          type: 'confirmation',
          extra: `Calendar ID ${mailer.params.cid} with procedure ${cData.procedure}`
        }
      );
      debug('message sent, update the database');
      await mailer.db.exec(async connection => {
 ...
       });
      debug('success');
    } else {
      debug('invalid calendarid');
      throw new Error('Invalid Calendar ID');
    }
  };
```

As can be seen the call path from the `async send` function which throws back up the stack to the `try {}catch(){}`  are all async functions.  But when I run this test node outputs an unhandled promise rejection.

I've tried using the visual studio code debugger to single step through this, I get a bit lost caught in the machinery which wraps async functions to turn them into promises providers.  As far as I can see, one layer of error is handled correctly and then fails at the next layer up.

Does this mean that every async function must have a try catch block to catch and rethrow any error? I can't find any explanation that says I have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Does this mean that every async function must have a try catch block to catch and rethrow any error?

Errors propogate up through `await`-ed calls like you expected:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const outer = async () => {
  await middle();
}

const middle = async () => {
  await inner();
}

const inner = async () => {
  throw new Error('something bad happened');
}

it('should catch the error', async () => {
  let errorMessage;
  try {
    await outer();
  }
  catch (err) {
    errorMessage = err.message;
  }
  assert(errorMessage === 'something bad happened');  // Success!
});
```

...so no, you don't need a `try / catch` block at every level.

---

**Tracking down unhandled `Promise` rejections**

I can't see exactly where the `await` chain might be broken in the code from your sample, but to help track down unhandled `Promise` rejections you can add a [process handler for the `unhandledRejection` event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) and look at the logged `Promise` to see where the rejection began and track backwards through the call stack from there:

```
const assert = require('assert');

const outer = async () => {
  await middle();
}

const middle = async () => {
  inner();  // <= this will cause an Unhandled Rejection
}

const inner = async () => {
  throw new Error('something bad happened');
}

it('should catch the error', async () => {
  let errorMessage;
  try {
    await outer();
  }
  catch (err) {
    errorMessage = err.message;
  }
  assert(errorMessage === undefined);  // Success!  (broken await chain)
})

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p);
  console.log('reason:', reason);
});
```

...which in this case logs:

```
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise {
  <rejected> Error: something bad happened
      at inner (.../code.test.js:12:9)
      at inner (.../code.test.js:8:3)
      at middle (.../code.test.js:4:9)  // <= this is the broken link
      at Context.outer (.../code.test.js:18:11)
      at callFn (...\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:387:21)
      ...
```

...which points us to the `Error` thrown in `inner`, and by tracing up the chain we find `middle` to be the broken link.

Comment: I think you've nailed it.  I think its actually one of the mocks that I didn't show that is doing a process.nextTick().  I appears the error occurs when I'm inside that

Comment: Actually I am wrong.  The failure occurs inside the "internal" `next_tick` function. I am struggling on how to correct this, as there is no obvious place for me to add the rejection handler.